# React native debugger is too slow

Tags: debugging, react-native

Ok so this is really been a headache for me. I have been trying to develop a react native app but the Debug JS feature on chrome makes it run very very slowly. Each button click and transition takes almost a couple of minutes and sometimes longer making debugging close to impossible.

I have removed many of the unused console.log statements to try and speed things up. I have also pulled the debugging tab into its own separate window. But there no real change in speed. I have also tried to connect the phone over wifi to debug it. I am running the code on the hardware device and have already tried the suggestions given in the following posts

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10559
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5632

What is the best approach to make the debugging faster and more tolerable?

Comment: Did you try the [standalone debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) they mentioned? I had similar problems with debug slowness when using Chrome. I eventually tried out react-native-debugger and found it to be much faster.

Comment: You can try Reactotron if you're using a Mac. Its gives you the option to resend actions also (redux) as well as all kinds of logging

Comment: I have tried both the standalone debugger, and also react-native-debugger, and I still get the same issue.

Comment: I've tried just about everything including all the suggestions in this question and many different iterations of emulator images, settings, and even different computers. None of it helps. There seem to be fundamental issues with RN on Android that make it impossible to debug. I've come to the conclusion that Android debugging just isn't a priority for the React Native team. If you want workable debugging on a RN app you need a mac with the iOS simulator. It works flawlessly there.

Answer (score 47):

Check the clocks on your phone and your computer. 
In my case, the lagging occurs when the phone's clock is behind the computer's clock for more than a second. The issue resolved when I changed the phone's clock to a few seconds ahead of the computer.

Comment: WOW! It was off by barely 1 second and switching so that both the device and my machine were using the same time sync server "time.apple.com" fixed the problem!

Comment: On a Samsung Galaxy s7 I did not see away to change the time, it just uses network time. I went to the site time.is and saw my Windows 8 pc was almost 5 seconds off. I went to "Date and Time" settings  and found "time-a.nist.gov" worked really well.

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you

Comment: On Windows 10 right click the clock in the task bar, select "Adjust date/time", then press the "sync now" button.  That fix the issue for me. Also <rant>The fact that this is the problem is ridiculous</rant>

Comment: This can also be the issue when the phone is ahead of the computer, so I recommend to sync them up as close as possible (internet sync should be sufficient). You can check the time of your phone and computer with `adb shell "date" && date` while the device is connected via USB.

Comment: Mindblown by how this was the solution! Thanks

Comment: this is ridiculous! thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 14):

My solution was to turn off the react "React Developer Tools" extension for Chrome. Really made a big difference. Note: I use the "React Native Debugger".

Comment: Yup, might be specific to this application but it also fixed my lag issues

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. Also using Chrome instead of the "React Native Debugger" app made it much faster.

Comment: Chrome extension much faster! actually, I just need to see logs :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to deactivate the "Slow animation" option in the debug menu of the simulator?

I had the same issue and that did the trick when running my app in the ios simulator.

Comment: In my case it is exactly that easy problem! Anyway, how could that happen? I never remember ever switched on that option!

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable "Dev Settings" -> "JS Dev Mode" -> Reload.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking `Slow Animations` in `Debug` option of Simulator does the trick! Very simple.

Comment: Doesn't mean anything! Unchecked and still slooooww.

Answer (score 0):

**try to comment all `console.log` things on your project**, then check the running speed. the remote debugging is load on your browser (chrome v8) and because of that the app loading is not gonna be to slow.

Answer (score 0):

Using the debugger in [Opera](https://www.opera.com/download) helped me quite a bit with performance in Debug mode. I also noticed that profiling temporarily fixes the performance in Chrome's devtools.

Answer (score 0):

In React Native Debugger, right click -> just select 'Toggle React DevTools' and close react dev tools window

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, the lagging occurs when the phone's time is behind the
> computer's time. when I
> changed the phone's clock to a few seconds pr few minutes ahead of the computer.
> It's really working super fast now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bundle location

Install the app again.

npx react-native run-android
or
yarn react-native start andoird

Open React native debugger
Open the dev Menu and select debugging